# YouTube API - using PHP and xml user feed to retrieve last video uploads

Tags: php, foreach, youtube-api, simplexml

so I was trying to get last 5 YouTube user uploads through feed, and I ended with this code found online:

```
function yt_last_5() {
for($i = 0; $i < 5; ){
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . yt_user_id(). '/uploads?max-results=5';
        $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
        foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
                $media = $entry->children('media', true);
                $url = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
                $index = strrpos($url, "&");
                $url = substr($url, 0, $index);
                $index = strrpos($url, "watch");
                $url = substr($url, 0, $index) . "v/" . substr($url, $index + 8, strlen($url) - ($index + 8));
                echo '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="400" height="250" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="src" value="' . $url . '" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="250" src="' . $url . '" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object><br />';
                break;
        }
        $i++;
}
}
```

The problem is that it shows the last uploaded video 5 times, actually I want it to retrieve the last 5 videos instead of repeating a single one.

last word: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please bear in mind that the gData API (Data API v2) that you are using here will be discontinued April 20, 2015. http://youtube-eng.blogspot.nl/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3_4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two loops inside each other.

One counts from 0 to 5:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; )
// some code
$i++; // this could just be in the for(), by the way
```

Inside that, you have some code which does the same thing every time, ignoring the counter. That contains a loop which looks at each video in turn:

```
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
```

But before it has a chance to look at anything other than the first entry, you break out of the inner loop:

```
break;
```

You only need one loop or the other.

Using the counter approach, you could use `$i` to reference a particular entry in the XML:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $entry = $sxml->entry[$i];
    // display a video
}
```

Beware that this will fail if there are ever less than 5 entries; you could fix that by testing `isset($sxml->entry[$i])`.

Using the `foreach` loop, you could count how many videos you've echoed and `break` *when you get to the 5th*:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i = 0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
    $i++;
    // display a video
    if ( $i == 5 ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: " But before it has a chance to look at anything other than the first entry, you break out of the inner loop:

`break;` "


@IMSoP thank you so much, I have placed `break;` right after `$i++;` and everything worked fine.
You are awesome !